# enable browser scrollbar working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have html like below

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#parent {
 position : absolute;
 width : 500px;
 height : 500px;
}
#top {
 position : absolute;
 width : 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index : 5;
}

#bottom {
 position : absolute;
 width : 100%;
 height : 100%;
 overflow :auto ;
 z-index : -1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="parent">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <iframe id="bottom" src="https://www.baidu.com"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the scrollbar will show when "bottom" is overflow.

Since bottom div is under top div, scrolling is not working.

My target is that mouse cannot directly click on any element in "bottom" div, but can use mouse wheel and drag scrollbar to achieve "bottom" scrolling.

Comment: Don't use `z-index` if you just want to make the whole div unclickable, remove those `z-index`s and add `pointer-events: none` to your bottom div. Hmm i'll add this as an answer I don't know why i put it here.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `z-index` if you just want to make the whole div unclickable, remove those `z-index`s and add `pointer-events: none` to your bottom div.

Like:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="top">I don't know what's the use of this</div>
    <div id="bottom" style="overflow:auto; pointer-events: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question. Because top div is a marker, I will add some dynamic div in the top div .so the top div must show before.

Answer (score 0):

Replace overflow: hidden;
Also add  **style="overflow:hidden;"**  in the parent div.